# How should dates be posted to java?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, date

I always had this doubt and always had problems with this. The thing is that, for example, I have a form that requests the user to enter a date and the it is posted via ajax to the server and it receives the date field as a Date type. Some times, what I did was to send the different values in different params, like this:

```
{
    day: 18,
    month: 05,
    year: 2014,
    hour: 10,
    min: 30
}
```

And then in the server, make the Date type from the values received.
But then, of course, I thought this was not a good practice and I started to make a string like this:

```
{
     date: "2014-09-16T12:00:00Z"
}
```

but this of course, does not take in account the location of the user in order to keep the corresponding GMT+-..

I also thought about posting the milliseconds, but here again, there is the problem with the GMT..

I am using spring, just for the record.

So, how should it be done? What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: Just grab the time zone as well?

Comment: @mc10 Should that be done in javascript or in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Think And Store In UTC

Generally best to store and work with date-time values in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Translate to a local date-time only for presentation when expected by the user. If it is important to know the data-entry user's [time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Offsets_from_UTC), record that separately in addition to the UTC value.

## Ask For Time Zone

As for determine the time zone or offset from a user on a client machine, in a web browser you could ask via JavaScript as suggest in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25627383/642706). But ultimately, if the time zone or offset is really important, you should ask the user. Present a list for them to choose. Use [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), never 3 or 4 letter codes. Those codes are neither standardized nor unique.

You cannot trust the clock on users’ computers. When you need to know the current time for any important purpose, use your server’s time since you have control over that machine. And be sure that server computer is hooked up to one or more [time servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server).

## Serialize to ISO 8601

When serializing date-time values to a string, using the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is definitely the way to go.

The new java.time package in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29) extends ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone. Interesting idea, but not standard afaik.

## Do Not Track Count From Epoch

Tracking date-time by a count since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) is meaningless to humans which makes debugging and verification tricky and error-prone. Date-time libraries internally track a count from epoch. But we have those libraries for a reason, to make the programming work easier and more correct. Some geeky types of people may suggest this approach. But they are often naïve about how tricky and thorny is date-time work.

Furthermore, different environments and libraries use different scales: whole seconds, [milliseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), [microseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), and [nanoseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). And about [two dozen epochs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) have been used in various computer systems.

## Avoid j.u.Date & .Calendar

Never use the java.util.Date and .Calendar classes bundled with Java. They are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided. Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) added to Java 8 to supplant those old classes.

## LocalDate & LocalTime

Good libraries such as [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) offer classes for when you want a date-only or time-of-day-only without time zone offset.

But do not use these thinking that ignoring time zones will make your life easier. Use these only when you mean something like "Company policy is that our factories in Detroit, Marseille, and Helsinki will stop for lunch at 12:30 PM". The factories don't stop simultaneously, but rather at their own particular occurrence of 12:30.

If instead you mean the company president will make a live webcast at 10 AM Detroit time, store that value as adjusted to UTC. Then upon presentation to users, adjust again to their own Detroit, Marseille, or Helsinki time.

Comment: Thanks, this explanation is very useful. I have another question, if I have some dates that they don't mater the UTC value, I should store them in UTC and the set in JAVA the timezone to 0 in order to not alter it, am I right?

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez I added the last section as an answer to your comment. Also, search StackOverflow before posting, as these issues have been discussed hundreds of times.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getTimezoneOffset()` in JavaScript to get the offset, then apply that to make all of the times in the local GMT

[JavaScript getTimezoneOffset() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)